# Is "Should I be of further assistance, please feel free to contact me" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I was wondering if "Should I be of further assistance, please feel free to contact me" was grammatically correct. What I basically want to say is that if I can be of any further assistance, please feel free to contact me.

Thank you!

PS: Directed to prospective employer.

Comment: While perhaps grammatically correct, it doesn't mean what you want to say and I'd stick with your basic instinct: "If I can be of any further assistance, please feel free to contact me." I read the version you propose as meaning: "If I help you any more, be sure to contact me [so that I can send you a bill]. If you insist on using "should," maybe this would be closer to what you want to say: "Should you feel that I can be of [any] further assistance, please feel free to contact me."

Comment: No problem! Regardless of how you phrase the first clause, you could also rephrase the last clause ("please feel free to contact me") to "[please] don't hesitate to contact me." (I noticed that my original suggestion had one too many "feels" in it but it was too late to edit it when I saw that, so I'm glad you responded, giving me a second chance to mention that alternate ending!)(ps.I already upvoted your question from the get go, or I'd do it now...)

Answer (score 7):

It is grammatically correct. It, however, doesn't mean what you seem to think it does.

What that sentence means is roughly, 'If I end up assisting you, please feel free to contact me', which doesn't make a lot of sense, unless you're requesting that they thank you afterwards.

Instead, you can say "If you believe I can be of any further assistance, please feel free to contact me.", which is perfectly acceptable to send to a prospective employer.

If you for some reason need to stay close to that structure, Papa Poule's suggestion of "Should you feel I can be of further assistance, ..." is also correct and acceptable.